# .equals method for String class and user defined class

Tags: java

The .equals method in the 1st case compares the content and gives true but in the 2nd case it gives false, why?  For the second case, why is it not true?

```
public abstract class Base {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //case 1
        String s1=new String("abc");
        String s2=new String("abc");

        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); //true

        //case 2
        Child c =new Child("abc");
        Child c1=new Child("abc");

        System.out.println(c.equals(c1)); //false
        }
    }

    public class Child extends Base{
        private String obj;


        public Child(String string) {
            this.obj=string;
            //System.out.println(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
true
false
```

Comment: In the second case you are comparing `objects`. You must override the `.equals` of the `Object` class

Comment: Does Child, or any of its superclasses other than Object, declare a .equals method?

Answer (score 1):

To test for value equality in the `Child` class, you need to `Override` equals. Because the default `Object` version compares references -

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) { // <-- reference identity test.
        return true;
    }
    if (o instanceof Child) {
        Child c = (Child) o;
        return obj.equals(c.obj);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I got it..Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Elliott what is obj and c.obj here?

Comment: @supun the only field defined in child in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

The equals() method compares two objects for equality and returns true if they are equal. The equals() method provided in the Object class uses the identity operator (==) to determine whether two objects are equal. For primitive data types, this gives the correct result. For objects, however, it does not. The equals() method provided by Object tests whether the object references are equal—that is, if the objects compared are the exact same object.

To test whether two objects are equal in the sense of equivalency (containing the same information), you must override the equals() method. Here is an example of a Book class that overrides equals():

```
public class Child{
    ...
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Child)
            return ISBN.equals((Child)obj.getISBN()); 
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Consider this code that tests two instances of the Book class for equality:

```
Child firstChild  = new Child("0201914670");
Child secondChild = new Child("0201914670");
if (firstChild.equals(secondChild )) {
    System.out.println("objects are equal");
} else {
    System.out.println("objects are not equal");
}
```

This program displays objects are equal even though firstChild and secondChild reference two distinct objects. They are considered equal because the objects compared contain the same ISBN number.

You should always override the equals() method if the identity operator is not appropriate for your class.

source : [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `equals()` method on custom objects.

```
class Child {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherObj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.obj.equals(otherObj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public boolean equals(Object anObject) : This method is overridden in String and all the wrapper class in java, so your case 1 returns true.

```
//case 1

//.equal method are overriden in String class
    String s1=new String("abc");
    String s2=new String("abc");

    System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); //true
```

When you create your custom class, it actually make use of its super class equal method, i.e of Object class.
All you need is to override equals method in your class to behave properly.